# how to database design for user authentication like student, teacher , super admin

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create different types of registration for user . I have got three collection for users . I have been references user collection in both of teacher and student because I need to get email and password.

If a teacher register including email, password, firstname , lastname etc , there is a collection .

if a student register including email, password, firstname , lastname etc , there is another collection .

our all of email and password will be one collections

user - table/collection
- email : test@gmail.com
- password: asdfasdf

student - table /collection
- firstname: 'sujon"

teacher - table/collection
- firstname: "sujon"

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
})


const StudentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
    },
    firstname: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
    },
    photo: {
        type: String,
    },
    education: {
        type: String,
    },
    birth: {
        type: Date,
    },
    sex: {
        type: Boolean,
    },
})
  const TeacherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  firstname: {
    type: String
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String
  },
  photo: {
    type: String
  },
  designation: {
    type: String
  },
  birth: {
    type: Date
  },
  sex: {
    type: Boolean
  }
   });
```

how can implement database design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a single User schema would be fine. You can have a single schema with all properties (since all three types of user have almost same properties) and then add a 'roles' field like this:

```
roles: [{ type: String }]
```

The roles field can have multiple roles [ 'Teacher', 'Student' ... ]. In this way a single user can have multiple roles for example a Teacher can also be an admin etc.

Also you won't have to create a new model whenever a new role is introduced.

Users can be queried based on their roles. The roles can then be used for authentication as well for example a user with role 'Teacher' can create assignment or a user with role 'Student' can submit assignments. When registering a user you can set some sort of model validation on the api or client side to accept a certain model.

Comment: can you design model for user ? I am little bit confused

Comment: `const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    roles: [{
        type: String
    }],
    // All other optional fields.
})`

Comment: is there any problem if I used three collections for role based authentication

Comment: Yes few of the problems are: 
1- You'll have to add a new collection whenever you create a new role. 
2- A single user can't be assigned multiple roles.
3- Different login functions for each collection.

Comment: thanks for your comments . you save me , but right now working with roles . how  can i use roles during authentication .

Comment: If you're using JWT, pass the roles array in JWT then while decoding check if the correct role exists.